# lazy loading screen - react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

New to react-navigation and trying to lazy load a screen. I'm using the new version `1.0.0-beta.27`, but it seems like both lazyLoading and lazy doesn't work in this version. Is there any other way to implement this?

My code:

```
const MainNavigator = TabNavigator({
      welcome: { screen: WelcomeScreen },
      login: { screen: LoginScreen},
      main: {
        screen: TabNavigator({
          map: { screen: MapScreen },
          deck: { screen: DeckScreen },
          review: {
            screen: StackNavigator({
              review: { screen: ReviewScreen },
              settings: { screen: SettingsScreen }
            })
          }
        })
      }
    }, {
        lazy: true
    });
```

Comment: Not the solution you're looking for, but I suggest to downgrade to `beta.22` until the [new method](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/3292#issuecomment-358313366) to lazy load tab content is ready.

Comment: This was the best solution, thanks @Jonas. I spent a lot of time trying to figure this out.

Comment: At "react-navigation": "^1.5.9", lazy: true is working well.